# String-Conditionals in a Java While Loop

Tags: java

I'm trying to prompt the user to give me one of three strings: "Amsterdam," "Lexington," and "Madison." If the user doesn't enter one of those strings, they should be repeatedly prompted until they do so.

When I type a string that's supposed to be acceptable, like "Lexington," I still receive "Please enter a valid city."

Can anyone tell me how the While loop is being run even when I'm negating the conditionals in it?

```
    public String readCity() {
        String x = keyboard.next();
        while (!x.equals("Amsterdam") || !x.equals("Lexington") || !x.equals("Madison")) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid city.");
            x = keyboard.next();
        }
    return x;
    }
```

Comment: Use && not || as your conditional

Comment: You could also store the cities in an ArrayList and just do an `if (!cityArray.contains(x))`. This would also shorten your if-statement, especially if more cities are added later

Comment: your condition says that if userInput is not equal to A or B or C, please enter valid city. Problem is if you give valid input (eg. A), still it is not equal to B/C and hence still 'or' condition holds true. Change 'or' to 'and'

Comment: Think about it - if `x` contains "Amsterdam", then what does `!x.equals("Amsterdam")` return? What does `!x.equals("Lexington")` return? What does `!x.equals("Madison")` return? What happens when you `||` those things together?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Refer to [De-Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

```
(NOT a) OR (NOT b)
```

is actually

```
NOT (a AND b)
```

You need to have `&&` instead of `||`.

Comment: It's actually `NOT (a AND b)`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `AND` instead of `OR` like this:

```
String x = keyboard.next();
while (!x.equals("Amsterdam") && !x.equals("Lexington") && !x.equals("Madison")) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a valid city.");
    x = keyboard.next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Java 7 or above I would prefer the following code:

```
public String readCity() {
    while (true) {
        String x = keyboard.next();

        switch(x) {
            case "Amsterdam":
            case "Lexington":
            case "Madison":
                return x;
            default:
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid city.");
         }
    }
}
```